How to install libshout using cmake in Windows 11 (NO MSYS2 answers)?
How to install libshout (and all it dependencies) in Windows 11 using cmake or vcpkg?
I don't want msys2/mingw answers.
I sucessfully build libogg, libvorbis and speex with cmake but i cannot install libshout with cmake or vcpkg (with vcpkg there is no such module available).
I want /include and /lib paths to use it while building python-shout module in windows 11.
Edit: If it's not possible to build and install libshout using cmake or vcpkg then it could be great to install it using Visual Studio.
I have found this source: https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/xiph/releases/libshout/

The library supports only building via Autotools (note on files like Makefile.am, configure.ac). It doesn't support building with CMake. Also, on Windows Autotools is available only via msys/mingw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65555603/how-to-produce-a-configure-script-for-windows-with-autotools.
